# copying file from one repo to another repo using Groovy Script

Tags: shell, devops

I need a help on this. To clone the repo, copy the files into local directory and then push the files into another repo with git commands using Groovy Script for to Run the Jenkins Job.

Answer (score 1):

- Clone the repo to a local folder.
- Delete the "hidden" `.git`
- Import folder to new repo